# Problem with Patroling "AI". Unit patrols from point to point from list of transforms, works correct on prototype. Don't work when used from perfab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Enemy Patroling method:

```
private void Patrol()
{
    if (patrolCounter < patrolPoints.Count)
    {
        if (enemy.transform.position != patrolPoints[patrolCounter].position)
        {
            target = patrolPoints[patrolCounter].position;
        }
        else
        {
            patrolCounter++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        patrolCounter = 0;
    }
    enemy.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(enemy.transform.position, target, step);
}
```

This is only a part of the script.

Everything works fine when I attach the script to the enemy obj, but when I make a prefab and drag it to the scene again, the enemy stops on the first patrol point.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by multiple reasons.

1. You forgot to set specific values on your prefab in the inspector (e.g. number of waypoints)
2. You forgot to add components to the script after you dragged it onto the prefab which causes it to break after the first waypoint

Do you get any error messages?